JavaScript can't cooperate with HTML in independent files, they work in same HTML file
So i made this simple game of clicking a button, timer is set to 5 seconds and counter will go up with each click (everything works in same file [index.html]). Whenever i try to put the code to independent files such as js.js and index.html with anchor of:
<script src="js.js"></script>

It just doesn't work and it shows error such: Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
Here is the JS and HTML code:
// Global variables
const clickButton = document.getElementById('clickButton');
const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');

// Counter
let counter = 0;
clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter++;
  counterElement.textContent = counter;
  moveButtonRandomly();
});

// Timer
let timeLeft = 5;
let timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
let timer;

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
        timeLeft--;
        timerElement.textContent = timeLeft;
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert('Game Over! You lose!');
    }
};

function startTimer() {
    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timeLeft = 5;
    timerElement.textContent = timeLeft;
}

document.getElementById('startofthegame').addEventListener('click', startTimer);
document.getElementById('clickButton').addEventListener('click', startTimer);


// Random button position
function moveButtonRandomly() {
  const randomX = Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - clickButton.offsetWidth);
  const randomY = Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - clickButton.offsetHeight);
  clickButton.style.left = randomX + 'px';
  clickButton.style.top = randomY + 'px';
}

// Start of the actual game after clicking "START!" button
document.getElementById("startofthegame").addEventListener("click", moveButtonRandomly);
const start = document.getElementById("startofthegame");
start.addEventListener("click", hidden)
function hidden() {
 var button = document.querySelector(".hidden");
button.classList.remove("hidden")
var button2 = document.querySelector(".text")
button2.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
}

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Random Position Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">
  <p>Welcome to simple clicking game!</p>
<button id="startofthegame" class="start">Start!</button>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
<button id="clickButton" onclick="resetTimer()">Click me</button>
<p>Counter: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
<p>Time left: <span id="timer">5</span> seconds</p>
</div>
</script>

</body>
</html>


I've tried loading page by using DOMContentLoading, and it still didn't work, tried redoing some lines of code and still failed and the whole page was broken. I really don't know how to solve this issue.
(Sorry if my code is spaghetti and some of you could do it in 50% less lines but i am a begginer and wanted to try something myself)

Your javascript runs at the point of <script src=js.js - at this point, your elements don't exist.  Either wrap in a ready event, or, easier, move <script src=js.js to just before </body> (which it looks like it used to be given the erroneous </script> there).   In head/end of body is a style issue - but if it's in head, you need the cater for it.

Thank you fdomn-m, your answer helped me solve this problem, thank you again.

The reason for the error is because the code is executed before the body is even created. So clickButton does not exist yet.
You simply need to run the code at the right time, which is once the DOM content is finished loading. You can do this by using an eventHandler on the DOMContentLoaded event of the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    // Insert JS code here
});

The weird part tough, is that this should have been needed even if the javascript was present directly in your page. I assume the javascript was not put in the head before and was at the end of the body? Placing the scripts at the end of the body is common practice.

Alternatively, the <script ...></script> can be moved right before </body> to ensure the DOM is rendered when the JavaScript is executed. And yes, you can tell his script was originally at the bottom of the page, because the closing </script> at the bottom is still present in his code example.

See this existing answer which goes into a lot more detail with different solutions.

Right, it was sure there would be a duplicate somewhere!

Maybe I just pasted the DOM content in wrong place and it didn't work as it should do, but i'll try to improve the "game" and use dom content method in many more JS scripts in the future.

@Salketer there's always a duplicate!   I'm trying to get my js gold badge, but just keep closing questions instead!  lulz
